# String adjustment by identify position of last letter

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, string

I have these different versions of product IDs:
Example 01: CA58762A090604
Example 02: X96017A096602
Example 03: CA61126D149403
Example 04: L00124B1154728

Let me break it up, it consists of
*Product - Color - Size* like this
Example 01: CA58762A 0906 04
Example 02: X96017A 0966 02
Example 03: CA61126D 1494 03
Example 04: L00124B 1154 728

These might be examples of products unfortunately added to a order cancellation email, due to out of stock etc.

In that email I want to recommend similar products, but I order to make my product recommendation logic work I need to remove the size from the product id, and have these things to consider:

- The length of the product part of the product id varies. In the examples above it's either 7 or 8 characters long
- The length of the size part of the product id varies. In the examples above it's either 2 or 3 characters long

On the other hand, what I **can** rely on is that I can always remove everything from the product ID string 4 places to the right of the last **letter**.

**How would you solve turning these product id's into these with AMPscript?**
CA58762A090604 into CA58762A0906
X96017A096602 into X96017A0966
CA61126D149403 into CA61126D1494
L00124B1154728 into L00124B1154

Thank you

Comment: Does this help [SubString](https://ampscript.com/substring-function/) () function

Comment: @VishalKumarCV OP needs to remove 4 characters from the last letter in the string, so it will be a bit more complex - a combination of regex and substring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very quick and dirty, but should work. As described in your question, it subtracts the last portion of the string and checks whether it contains a letter or not. Then, based on that it subtracts after 4 characters from the last letter:

```
%%[

set @string = "L00124B1154728"
set @len = length(@string)
set @subract = Subtract(@len,6)
set @substring = Substring(@string,@subract,7)
set @letters = "^([A-Z]{1})(\d{1})([A-Z\d]+)$"
set @regex = RegExMatch(@substring, @letters, 1)

if not empty(@regex) then 
    set @product = Substring(@string,1,add(@subract,4))
else 

    set @subract = Subtract(@len,7)
    set @substring = Substring(@string,@subract,8)
    set @letters = "^([A-Z]{1})(\d{1})([A-Z\d]+)$"
    set @regex = RegExMatch(@substring, @letters, 1)

        if not empty(@regex) then 
        set @product = Substring(@string,1,add(@subract,4))
        endif
endif
]%%

@product: %%=v(@product)=%%
```

Comment: Well, it might be quick and dirty, but I've just tested it in a live environment. It's brilliant and works like a charm. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use SSJS for this and match the location with a regEx.

```
<script runat="server" language="ampscript">
SET @originalproductid = 'X96017A096602' 
</script>

<script runat=server language="JavaScript" >
  Platform.Load('Core', '1')
   var originalproductid = Variable.GetValue('@originalproductid');
    var match = /\d{1}[a-zA-Z]\d{4}/.exec(originalproductid);
if (match) {
  var location = match.index;
Variable.SetValue('@location',location);
}
</script>

<script runat="server" language="ampscript">
SET @newproductid = Substring(@originalproductid,0,Add(@location,6))                          
</script>


newproductid: %%=treatascontent(@newproductid)=%%<br>
```